# Linq Table Group By Get Perecentage in each column

Tags: c#, linq

I have a datatable with 2 columns:

```
GuitarBrand | Status
---------------------
Fender      | Sold
Fender      | In Stock
Gibson      | In Stock
Gibson      | In Stock
```

I want to write a linq query to output

```
 GuitarBrand | PercentSold | Sold/Total
 ---------------------------------------
 Fender      | 50%          | 1/2
 Gibson      | 100%         | 2/2
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
var groupedtable = from b in table.AsEnumerable()
    group b by b.Field<"GuitarBrand"> into g
    select new ( GuitarBrand = g.Key, Perecent = (float)g.Count()/(float)g.key)
```

Which I got from another post but it isn't even close to working, I get a Cannot Convert string to float. I've tried looking at other posts but I can't find anything.

Thanks!

Comment: try `float.Parse(g.Count())`/`float.Parse(g.Count(g.key))`

Comment: g.key is a string, you cannot divide number with string!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following (hopefully self explanatory) query:

```
var groupedtable = 
    from b in table.AsEnumerable()
    group b by b.Field<string>("GuitarBrand") into g
    let Total = g.Count()
    let Sold = g.Count(e => e.Field<string>("Status") == "Sold")
    let SoldPercent = (float)Sold / (float)Total
    select new
    {
        GuitarBrand = g.Key,
        PercentSold = SoldPercent.ToString("p"),
        TotalSold = Sold + "/" + Total
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like this!

```
var groupedtable = from b in table.AsEnumerable()
    group b by b.Field<"GuitarBrand"> into g
    select new { 
     GuitarBrand = g.Key, 
     Perecent = g.Count(x=>x.Status.Eguals("Sold")/(float)g.Count()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you started. In your question, your output table is contradicting. I've assumed you want the data as labeled.

```
public static void Main()
{
    var guitars = new List<Guitar>()
    {
        new Guitar(){ Brand = "Fender", Status = Status.Sold },
        new Guitar(){ Brand = "Fender", Status = Status.InStock },
        new Guitar(){ Brand = "Gibson", Status = Status.InStock },
        new Guitar(){ Brand = "Gibson", Status = Status.InStock }
    };

    var query = guitars
                    .GroupBy(guitar => guitar.Brand)
                    .Select(group => new 
                    { 
                        GuitarBrand = group.Key, 
                        Sold = group.Where(guitar => guitar.Status == Status.Sold).Count(),
                        Total = group.Count()
                    })
                    .Select(_ => new 
                    {
                        _.GuitarBrand,
                        PercentSold = ((decimal)_.Sold / (decimal)_.Total) * 100,
                        SoldAndTotal = string.Format("{0}/{1}", _.Sold, _.Total)
                    });
}

class Guitar {
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public Status Status { get; set; }
}

enum Status {
    Sold,
    InStock
}
```